# Decrease/Increase from member variable in rails via form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two classes `A` and `B`
`B` belongs to `A` and `A` has many `B`s with resources configured as:

```rb
  resources :as do
    resources :bs
  end
```

`B` has a member variable `amount` which I want to be able to decrease and increase from the front end using a form, in this case, it cannot be the edit form.

Can I do this at all? and can I do where the form opens in a pop up on following a link to?

The function I imagine for increase is something like this:

```rb
def increase()
   @b = b.find(params[:id])
   @b.amount = @b.amount + params[:amount]
   @.update
end
```

I Just cannot wrap my head around how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom route. Many diff non-resourceful routes in the [Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes) to check out.

One way is with the following:

- using `put` because this is an update request
- using `on: :member` to capture the bs `params[:id]` on the route

```rb
# routes.rb

resources :as do
  resources :bs do
    put 'increase_amount', on: :member
    put 'decrease_amount', on: :member
  end
end
```

```rb
# bs controller

def increase_amount()
   @b = B.find(params[:id])
   amount = @b.amount + params[:amount]
   if @b.update(amount: amount)
     ...
   else
     ...
   end
end

def decrease_amount()
   @b = B.find(params[:id])
   amount = @b.amount - params[:amount]
   if @b.update(amount: amount)
     ...
   else
     ...
   end
end
```

```
# haven't verified this is the correct route name, confirm using rake routes
<%= form_tag(increase_amount_a_bs_path(@a, @b), method: :put) do %>
  <%= label_tag(:amount, "Increase Amount:") %>
  <%= number_field_tag(:amount) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Update Amount") %>
<% end %>

<%= form_tag(decrease_amount_a_bs_path(@a, @b), method: :put) do %>
  <%= label_tag(:amount, "Decrease Amount:") %>
  <%= number_field_tag(:amount) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Update Amount") %>
<% end %>
```

As for the popup, I'm not sure what frontend library in your tech stack but Bootstrap comes to mind as an option, [modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/#modal-components)